# Will the Navigation2 GPS WPF be backported to Humble?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, nav2

I saw that a GPS Waypoint Follower including a demo was very recently merged into the main branch of the nav2 repository, great work! ([PR #2814](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/2814); [demo](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2_tutorials/pull/70)). The GPS WPF has already been backported to the ROS2 Iron distribution ([PR #3837](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/3837)).

Will there also be a backport to ROS2 Humble, since it has LTS? I already tried to do the backport myself and cherry-picked the [respective commit](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/commit/1efc96c3aa1b80d4926238238b56d45a9d7a8993), but it seems like there are more API changes in nav2 that need to be migrated as well. Does anybody know what changes are needed for the GPS WPF to work with Humble? I couldn't find an up-to-date overview with all breaking changes in nav2 between Humble and Iron.

Comment: This might be a question better suited for the github for that project, where the developers who might be responsible for doing this would be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It relies on items not available in Humble. Please upgrade to Iron or newer to use GPS Waypoint Follower